# How can I access PostGIS Topologies with C#?

Tags: postgis, c#, nettopologysuite, postgis-topology

I would like to access a PostGIS Topology with C#.

I looked through the [nPgSQL PostGIS/NetTopologySuite Type Plugin](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nts.html) but didn't see anything. With the word `topology` appearing in so many places, I may have overlooked something though.

Ideally, I'd like a method that returns a [NetTopologySuite.EdgeGraph](https://nettopologysuite.github.io/NetTopologySuite/api/NetTopologySuite.EdgeGraph.html) from a [PostGIS Topology](https://postgis.net/docs/Topology.html).

Comment: not a C# expert but does this help? https://github.com/apdevelop/linq2db-postgis-extensions. "Npgsql - the .NET data provider for PostgreSQL"

Comment: @Mapperz it looks like all those methods are for geometries. While it would be nice to have Linq methods for topologies too (e.g. for iterating through the edges connected to a node) I'd still need to retrieve the topology from the database first.